# Make shop page as home page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I've installed a aio theme and woocommerce plugin.

I can see products in `/shop`, but I want to see this on the homepage.
But the problem is that if I make it as a home page in `Settings->Reading`, it shows nothing.

Comment: WooCommerce definitely works on the frontpage. I was just looking at the template for that yesterday. So, I assume that your theme has something to disable this functionality. I'd test quickly against Twenty Fifteen just to verify. Then we can maybe proceed from there.

Answer (score 12):

**METHOD #1:**

It is the easy as well as simple method, it is as follows:

> Add `[products]` shortcode to your existing home page, update it and its
>   done.

If you need additional customization you can take help from this official link from [WooCommerce](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/)

**METHOD #2:**

> Follow these steps:
>
> **Step #1:** create a New Page, Give it a suitable Title (like: shop).
>
> **Step #2:** This is the important step, here you need to make sure that the permalink of this page must be like:
>   `http://YOUR-DOMAIN-NAME/shop/`
>
> Here `YOUR-DOMAIN-NAME` refers to your own website URL
>
> **Step #3:** Now go to `Settings->Reading` Select the above created Page as the Front page. save settings.
>
> **Step #4:** visit your website.

Comment: It was template problem, I think. I reinstalled wordpress, template & woocomerce, and it worked.